# The Gold Nugget Cipher

Tags: cipher

VPZ SPG FMAAVQ DJQF OB

.UTPQ TJIU PU ZMQFS FIU TB "NBI UBD" FUJSX FTBFMQ TJIU HOJEBFS FSB VPZ GJ

.kcul dooG

1-

Comment: !UJ FLJM VPZ GJ QV UJ FUPW FTBFMQ

Comment: Please don't use your questions for unrelated messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the text ".kcul doog" and "1-" indicate, the method to decode is

> reverse and shift each letter back by 1.

The result is:

> An epic puzzle for you
>
> If you are reading this please write "cat ham" as the reply to this post.

Comment: Good Job. Harder ones coming seeing how you got that so quick. lets see here...

Comment: That was only the first test.